# MySQL Subtotals of Rows with Grandtotal

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need to create a MariaDB SQL that will allow me to sum two columns (Debit & Credit Columns) to get the difference, as well as return the subtotal of every different account type. The table is as follows:

```
 Account     | Debit  | Credit
 acc1        |   1    |   2 
 acc1        |   1    |   4
 acc2        |   3    |   2
 acc2        |   2    |   1
 acc2        |   2    |   1
 acc3        |   5    |   2
 acc3        |   5    |   1
 acc3        |   5    |   2
```

I would like to return the following:

```
 Account     | Balance(debit-credit)
 acc1        |   -1    
 acc1        |   -3 
 -------------------------------
 Total acc1  |   -4 
 -------------------------------
 acc2        |   1
 acc2        |   1
 acc2        |   1
 -------------------------------
 Total acc2  |   3 
 -------------------------------
 acc3        |   3
 acc3        |   4
 acc3        |   3
 -------------------------------
 Total acc3  |   10 
 -------------------------------
 GrandTotal  |   9 
 -------------------------------

 Grandtotal is Totals of acc1 + acc2 + acc3
```

This is what I have tried so far, how ever all I am only getting the grandtotal and no subtotals

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT COALESCE(account,'TOTAL') AS Account, CASE
        WHEN account LIKE 'INC%' 
            THEN sum((gl.credit - gl.debit))
        ELSE sum((gl.debit - gl.credit))
    END AS Balance
 FROM `tabGL Entry` gl
 WHERE (NOT (account LIKE 'CASS%')
     AND NOT (account LIKE 'CLIA%')
     AND NOT (account LIKE 'FASS%'))
 GROUP BY account WITH ROLLUP
) AS gl
 ORDER BY CASE
     WHEN account LIKE 'INC%' THEN 1
     WHEN account LIKE 'DCOI%' THEN 2
     WHEN account LIKE 'DMC%' THEN 3
     WHEN account LIKE 'INFC%' THEN 4
     WHEN account LIKE 'IDEX%' THEN 5
     ELSE 6
 END
```

Comment: I cannot really imagine a circumstance where you'd have adjacent columns for debit and credit. That aside, you forgot to include your PRIMARY KEY, whose absence essentially makes this problem insoluble.

Comment: @Strawberry, the db I am working with is designed as such so kinda have to work with it. The type of account is the only basis by which I can go with, the primary key is not a key per se. Why would it be insoluble?. Regards

Comment: For the sake of a solution, lets disregard the sql statement above and used the dummy table result I've indicated also above, how would I write the sql statement?

Comment: It would have to be rather contrived I'm afraid. If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't really have a table. If you don't really have a table, then this isn't really an RDBMS question

Comment: @Strawberry, actually I do on all counts and re the primary key it does have  it. The reason I am asking based on a totally new sql statement is because clearly the one I have is not returning the needed results. Which is why I asked if there is another approach to the statement I indicated. Its defintely not contrived.

Comment: I don't know how you want me/us to respond to that.

Comment: That's fine, just replying to your earlier comment. :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'not a key per se'. If you have a PRIMARY KEY then share it with us. A PK can be a natural key formed on a combination of columns. It doesn't have to be a surrogate (although it simplifies the problem slightly if it is). Oh, and see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it with `UNION`, like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT COALESCE('TOTAL ', account) AS Account
               , SUM(CASE WHEN account LIKE 'INC%' 
                          THEN (gl.credit - gl.debit)
                          ELSE (gl.debit - gl.credit)
                      END) AS Balance
          FROM `tabGL Entry` gl
         WHERE (NOT (account LIKE 'CASS%')
           AND NOT (account LIKE 'CLIA%')
           AND NOT (account LIKE 'FASS%'))
         GROUP BY account WITH ROLLUP
  -- UNION SELECT account
  --              , CASE WHEN account LIKE 'INC%' 
  --                     THEN (gl.credit - gl.debit)
  --                     ELSE (gl.debit - gl.credit)
  --                 END AS Balance
  --         FROM `tabGL Entry` gl
  --        WHERE (NOT (account LIKE 'CASS%')
  --          AND NOT (account LIKE 'CLIA%')
  --          AND NOT (account LIKE 'FASS%'))
) AS gl
 ORDER BY CASE
 WHEN account LIKE 'INC%' THEN 1
 WHEN account LIKE 'DCOI%' THEN 2
 WHEN account LIKE 'DMC%' THEN 3
 WHEN account LIKE 'INFC%' THEN 4
 WHEN account LIKE 'IDEX%' THEN 5
 ELSE 6
END
```

I think this should do what you want

The commented-out part is for the single rows, the upper part for subtotals

Now after the last comment here the query that gives you the subtotals and the grandtotal

grouping by COALESCE seemed to be the Problem so now it's done by `LEFT(account,3)` and the `ORDER` Statement had to be modified to 3 Chars

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT LEFT(account,3) AS Account
           , SUM(CASE WHEN account LIKE 'INC%' 
                      THEN (credit - debit)
                      ELSE (debit - credit)
                  END) AS Balance
          FROM acc
         GROUP BY LEFT(account,3) WITH ROLLUP
) AS ac
 ORDER BY CASE
 WHEN account LIKE 'INC%' THEN 1
 WHEN account LIKE 'DCO%' THEN 2
 WHEN account LIKE 'DMC%' THEN 3
 WHEN account LIKE 'INF%' THEN 4
 WHEN account LIKE 'IDE%' THEN 5
 ELSE 6
END
```

Comment: RealCheeseLord. I tried your answer, unfortunately not working as expected, resutls are repeating rows. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: which rows are repeated? you didn't post all columns, so i don't know your `GROUP` key.

Comment: In this instance the `GROUP` key is the Account Column. The result of your statement is showing all Accounts instead of just the sum of a particular Account. For example -- Say there are 100 records for **acc1** then all 100 records are showing and not the sum of **acc1**. In the statement I gave the accounts  would "INC", "DCOI", "DMC", "INFC" and "IDEX" and I am grouping based on the account column. -- Thanks & Regards

Comment: ah, i missread your question, I edited and this should give you the subtotals. `SUM` outside of your `CASE`

Comment: RealCheeseLord -- I've applied your edited version and still not there, you can check the sqlfiddle here  [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/614b60/13/0) I have both statement on there with the original commented. Regards

Comment: @Said  try the updated Version :D  also: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/614b60/28

Comment: Awesome @RealCheeseLord, works like a charm  Thank You soo much Regards