# Sort rows by nearest to specified date but put records in the past to the end of result set

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, date

I just can't imagine how can this be done in SQL code but I feel it's possible.

I have the following records:

```
ID | NAME | REGDATE
1    sam    2017-08-12
2    gab    2017-08-13
3    mab    2017-08-19
4    mab    2017-08-20
5    don    2017-08-18
6    kob    2017-08-14
7    mol    2017-08-15
```

Now I want to sort the rows above like this:

```
ID | NAME | REGDATE
5    don    2017-08-18
3    mab    2017-08-19
4    mab    2017-08-20
7    mol    2017-08-15
6    kob    2017-08-14
2    gab    2017-08-13
1    sam    2017-08-12
```

What I want is to sort the rows to the nearest date today (which is 2017-08-18) and put the rows that has a `regdate` in the past in the end of the result set which you can see above.

How can this be possible in SQL?

I can't find the right term how can I search for an answer in the search engine. All I know is to use `order by` and that's it.

Comment: I've got a feeling that the query will use DateDiff

Comment: you can Combine `ORDER BY` and `CASE WHEN` like this guy did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582932/mysql-subtotals-of-rows-with-grandtotal/45583475#45583475

            it's not a direct solution for your Problem, but a good starting point

Comment: why is this voted unclear what i am asking? I already said what desired result i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using multiple keys for the `order by`:

```
order by ( regdate >= curdate() ) desc, -- put current and future first
         (case when regdate >= curdate() then regdate end) asc,
         regdate desc
```

Strictly speaking, the first condition is not necessary.  However, I think it makes the logic clearer.

Comment: yes, this works much more fine,and i voted this up :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
order by case when REGDATE > curdate() then 1 else 2 end, regdate
```

Comment: thank you for a very much more simpler approach :) but it works using ``>=``

Comment: @Mahan . . . This does not do what the question specifies.  The ordering of the dates in the past does not match what the question requests.